# Image arrow on an image map

Tags: android

Hey guys I am doing a project where I require to display arrow on a floorplan that guides people to escape . The arrow only show when there is fire. The floorplan right now I insert as image and the arrow is image as well . I set visibility to true when there is fire and viability gone where there is no fire, is that the correct way to do that? And also the position of the arrow on the xml file is different when I run it with my real phone.

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/a1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp" />



<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="190dp"
    android:onClick="button1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Fine to use visibility to show/hide - making sure it lines up would require us seeing your layout.xml file (include this)

Comment: @Booger, i have added in, thx for ur time to help

Comment: Any idea? I still can't solve it